# Angular 4 - fetch file from /src folder during development

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In `/src` folder I have file `abc.json`. On development machine I should get it with url http://localhost:3000/abc.json. On production machine this file is generated on-fly.

I used Angular 2 - project was generated by CLI 1.0.0-beta.26. And after command

```
npm start
```

I could fetch `abc.json`.

The start command is:

```
"start": "ng serve --port=3000"
```

Then I generated new project using CLI 1.2.6 (Angular 4.3.2 - the latest at the moment of writing). And now the response from this URL is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Cannot GET /sessionInformation.json</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

What should I change to allow to download `abc.json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The development server is not able to access the `src` dir.

You will need configure this file as an asset.

```
// .angular-cli.json
"assets": [
  "assets",
  "favicon.ico",
  "abc.json"
]
```

You can read more [here in the docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration)